# Refreshing UserDefaults Variable not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a navigation view that uses User defaults, when I am on a different page I have a button that adds += 1 to the userDefualts variable. When I go back there, it doesn't refresh unless I swipe the app. That is super weird, what I want to happen is it automatically refreshes when I enter that page.

Nav View that I need refreshed:

```
struct Analytics: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel = VariableViewModel()

 HStack {
                    // Problems compleated
                    Text(" Amount of problems compleated:")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text(String(viewModel.problemsCompleated))
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .bold()
                        .offset(x: -5, y: 0)
                }.offset(x: 0, y: 5)
}
```

Nav View were the variables sit and are being changed:

```
class VariableViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // analytics
    @Published var problemsCompleated = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "problemsCompleated")

problemsCompleated += 1
UserDefaults.standard.set(problemsCompleated, forKey: "problemsCompleated")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code, if you're using different instances of `VariableViewModel`, you won't see it refresh because it only ever pulls from `UserDefaults` on instantiation. So, when you go 'back' to the other page, it has no way of knowing that variable has been updated.

If you were just within your view, I'd recommend using `@AppStorage`, since it does all the lifting of checking and updating `UserDefaults` for you. In the `ObservableObject`, it's slightly more complicated, because `@AppStorage` won't trigger an update like `@Published`. But, it looks like by manually calling `objectWillChange` when the `@AppStorage` is set, we can get the best of both worlds:

```
class VariableViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("problemsCompleted") var problemsCompleted = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    func increment() {
        problemsCompleted += 1
    }
}
```